# Storing nested json into mysql db in node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to store the following data into a mysql db.

```
var data = {
    type: "binary",
    choices: [
    {
         choice: "No",
         answers: 18
    },
    {
         choice: "Yes",
         answers: 11
    }
   ],
    tags: {
         2851: "road",
         8685: "had",
         10978: "heard"
    }
  };
```

Choices is a javascript object var choices; and tags is var tags;
I want to store in just 3 columns of a mysql db.

I have tried JSON.stringify(choices) to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choices array and tags object are within the data object, so get them like this:

```
var choices = JSON.stringify(data.choices);
var tags = JSON.stringify(data.tags);
```

Comment: I figured the problem. I am the array was not filled yet when it was echoed! Node issues. :-)