# How to update JSON record in MySQL database using MySQL query in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, node.js

My JSON structure which I'm getting is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185461/storing-nested-json-into-mysql-db-in-node):

```
 var data = {
type: "binary",
choices: [
{
     choice: "No",
     answers: 18
},
{
     choice: "Yes",
     answers: 11
}
   ],
    tags: {
     2851: "road",
     8685: "had",
     10978: "heard"
    }
};
```

And I found the insertion of json record using MySQL query with Node.js in answer of same question.

Yes, I can update this record by getting whole record, Update record and replace old record with updated one.

BUT Here my question is **"Can i update these json record in database without downloading of full json and update these record based on one key from JSON?"**

**Note: this is just demo purpose: if my fied name is jsonData**

```
 "Update tableName set jsonData.choices.answers = 20 where data.choices.choice = 18 and id = 1";
```

Hope you understand my scenario to update JSON record one value based on one key.

Any conceptual suggestion will appreciated and if there is demonstration code than it will be very helpful.

Comment: What is the source of your JSON? A URL or a variable? You need complete object to traverse upon. Only picking partial object may not be possible. But still, if its a URL and it allows to get only certain prams based on request query params, then it can be done.

Comment: is it  ok if answer is in PHP ?

Comment: Source of JSON is variable as describe in question. and all keys are compulsory in my variable. And there is high possibility that many user will fire that update query at same time. So there is possibility that only latest update will affect in database. NO URL params included for JSON. @AshishChoudhary

Comment: Yes, its ok if it is in PHP. @thepiyush13

Answer (score 0):

Json decode the data which will convert it to an array, access array elements and append to query :

```
$a = json_decode($data);
"Update tableName set".$a->col1." =20......."
```

> PHP's json_decode function takes a JSON string and converts it into a
>   PHP variable. Typically, the JSON data will represent a JavaScript
>   array or object literal which json_decode will convert into a PHP
>   array or object.
>
> http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/decode.php

Comment: Here, You first select that record from tableview and parse it in to php variable and than update record. right?. Lets take simple and small case if there are 20 users which are firing same method at a time so there is possibility that one or more record might not be affected as they are fired on same time. right? Here I want direct update query to that record so if 100 users fired that at a time than the data should be accurate after all same 100 operations. Just one UPDATE  query no SELECT query for record.

Comment: The question is not quite clear to me but in case you are talking about concurrent update conflicts , in case of mysql, it uses repeatable read isolation level so If two transactions try to update the same row, the second transaction must wait for the first one to either commit or rollback, thus all the records will be inserted regardless of the timing. anyway good point, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm necromancing a long dead question, but sure, this is very simple with [MySQL's JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html).

```sql
UPDATE tableName
SET jsonData = JSON_SET(jsonData, '$.choices.answers', 20)
WHERE data->'$.choices.choice' = 18
  AND id = 1;
```

---

Read my [Best Practices for using MySQL as JSON storage](https://medium.com/@deltazero/mysql-as-smart-json-storage-200e6758f37e).